# Copy one file into every subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to `cp` one file: `index.php` into all subdirectories, and subdirectories of those subdirectories, and so on, so that every child directory of the root has `index.php`

I started with this:

```
for d in */; do cp index.php "$d"; done;
```

Which only worked for the top subdirectories. I tried to nest it in itself a few times like this:

```
for d in */; do cp index.php "$d"; for e in */; do cp index.php "$e";for f in */; do cp index.php "$f"; done; done; done
```

But that didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
find . -type d -exec cp index.php {} \;
```

### Note

- `-type d` find all dirs and sub-dirs

Comment: Almost worked. For every directory it said `omitting directory`

Comment: I think the `+` there should be `\;`

Comment: That doesn't work either, gives `cp: missing destination file operand after 'index.php./content/rest/of/path' `

Comment: @Chris: The space between `index.php` and `{}` is important.

Answer (score 1):

[sputnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465183/sputnick)'s answer is nice and simple. For the record, here is one way to do it with a shell function. You might want something like this if the operation is complicated or conditional.

```
t=$PWD/index.php

recurse () {
  for i in */.; do
    if [ "./$i" != './*/.' ]; then
      (cd "./$i" && cp "$t" . && recurse)
    fi
  done
}

recurse
```

Comment: Or, if we're talking bash: `shopt -s globstar; for d in **/*/; do cp foo "$d"; done`